# NSURLConnection not return data

Tags: objective-c, nsurlconnection

I Have a NSURLConnection that has been working for a while and all of a sudden is not working.

For some reason, the only delegate method that gets called is:

```
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:
```

None of the other delegate methods get called. I have other classes which uses pretty much the same code, just a different request and url and they all seem to work fine. I have read alot of post that talk about making sure the connection is on the same thread as the delegate etc but nothing seems to work for me. I know the server is returning a response because if I pass the same information through a simple html form I get a response in my browser, and I can see evidence that my server side script is running because I can see the changes it is making in the SQL data. And the app is getting some sort of resonse, its just not getting any data or calling the connectionDidFinishLoading delegate method.

Any ideas of what the problem might be?

Here is a simplified version on my code:

```
#import "RegistrationViewController.h"

@interface RegistrationViewController ()

@end

NSMutableData *responseData;
NSURLConnection *theconnection;

@implementation RegistrationViewController
/*
 *  Attempt to Register online. Returns False if valiation failed
 */
- (BOOL) registerOnline{

    // OTHER CODE HERE TO BUILD DATA FOR THE REQUEST

    // URL Request
    NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:THEURL];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestUrl];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodyData UTF8String] length:strlen([bodyData UTF8String])]];


    // Initialse Response Object
    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

    // Conection
    theconnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [theconnection start];

    return YES;
}

/*
 * Handle the event of registration failing
 */
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");

    // OTHER CODE HERE TO HANDLE THE ERROR....

}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    NSLog(@"did receive response ");

}

/*
 * Handle the reciept of Data
 */
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
    NSLog(@"didReceiveData");

    // Add data to the response
    [responseData appendData:data];\
}

/*
 * Data finnished loading
 */
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");

    // OTHER CODE HERE TO HANDLE THE RESPONSE....
}
```

Comment: By the way, are you percent-escaping the values captured in `bodyData` with `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes`? Also, if `bodyData` a string, `[request setHTTPBody:[bodyData dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]`.

Comment: Yeah, I am doing that, Just haven't show it above cause I didn't think that was necessary. I am confident that the server is receiving my request data successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the response and diagnose what's going on. For example, if `statusCode` is not `200`, you might have a problem. See the [HTTP/1.1 Status Code Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html).

So, you might check the `statusCode`:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
        NSInteger statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];

        if (statusCode == 200) {
            NSLog(@"received successful (200) response ");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"whoops, something wrong, received status code of %d", statusCode);
        }
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not a HTTP response");
    }
}
```

You're also calling:

```
theconnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

That starts the connection automatically. By calling

```
[theconnection start];
```

you're starting it a second time. Remove the `start` method, or use `initWithRequest:delegate:startImmediately:` with `NO` for that final parameter.

Comment: @user1775671 Very good. Try removing the redundant `start` method and see if that remedies the situation.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. I can't imagine that being much of a problem. Wouldn't that just make it send the request twice?

Comment: @user1775671 Yeah, you'd think it would just send it twice, but in my experience you actually get all sorts of unpredictable behavior. (Frankly, I don't know why they don't just make `start` just report some meaningful error/warning if you try to use it with a connection that is already in progress, but they don't.) I'm a little surprised that you saw no change in behavior when removing the redundant `start` call. Anyway, if it's still not working, you either have other problems in the construction of the request or in the server code. The limited code included in your question looks fine.

Comment: @user1775671 But I'm most surprised in your claim that you're seeing neither `connectionDidFinishLoading` nor `didFailWithError` called, even though you are seeing `didReceiveResponse` called with `statusCode` of 200, even after fixing the redundant `start` call. You're truly seeing `didReceiveResponse`, but nothing else?

Answer (score 0):

If it can help anybody, the problem for me was that i was starting the connection in an another thread

So be sure to call

```
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

or

```
theconnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
[theconnection start];
```

in the main thread.